# "Debug As..." in Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I'm an Android noob teaching myself debugging in the Eclipse (Galileo 3.52) environment.

I have a little "hello world" app that runs fine in the emulator.   So now I want to practice debugging by setting breakpoints, looking at variablaes, etc.

But Run > Debug As... has nothing but a grayed-out "(nothing applicable)" entry.    What does that mean and how do I configure it to say "Android application"?

I'm guessing it has something to do with the Run > Debug Configurations dialog, but it's not obvious to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have a java file selected and not an XML one or something?

Comment: Also, make sure that the application is marked as debuggable in the Android Manifest: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#debug

Comment: Yes, the java file is the one that's selected.    The debuggable attribute was not set at all.  I set it to true, cleaned and rebuilt, and nothing changed.  (BTW if it's not set at all what's the default behavior?)

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268081/debuging-simple-android-project/9273288#9273288