# "DeviceMonitor]Sending jdwp tracking request failed!" in Eclipse / Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, jdwp

I'm a noob learning Eclipse and Android.    Whenever I close the emulator I get "DeviceMonitor]Sending jdwp tracking request failed!" in the Console tab.  Infact that seems to be the ONLY thing I get in the console tab  -  I don't get all the emulator loading messages and other things I used to see.

Everything else seems to work, I can build, run in the emulator, debug in the emulator (via Run>Debug after setting a Debug configuration . . .  I can't get "Debug As" to work, see: ["Debug As..." in Eclipse for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974693/debug-as-in-eclipse-for-android) - don't know if that's relevant to this problem).

What does this message mean, and how do I correct it?    Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The message you receive is in the normal console of Eclipse and isn't really important, because it just reports you that the connection to the emulator was lost. That ok as you described you closed it.

The normal android log is only visible via the adb tool (via console) or with the view in Eclipse called LogCat. You can add that to your working screen if you go to Window -> View -> Other -> Android -> LogCat

I recommend to look at the other views of the android tools, too. Like Device or Explorer.

What might happen with the LogCat output is that it went blank. Than you need to clear the LogCat (there is a button for that on the top of the view) and if this doesn't help try to click on the emulator in the device list. If nothing of that helped: close eclipse and the emulator and start them again.

Comment: Once I get this message I don't get any other messages in the Console EXCEPT this message - even though I might get a new one every time I restart an emulator session.   So over a long afternoon of editing/testing I might have lots of these messages in the console but nothing else.

Comment: You know the difference between the eclipse console and the LogCat?

Answer (score 1):

Close eclipse, stop adb process. From command line, "adb kill-server".

Launch your eclipse project.

Comment: Yes, obviously that will do the trick.   But if I had to exit Eclipse and kill adb everytime I start getting this message I'd waste a lot of time just doing that?    Why do I keep Getting it and what do I have to do to stop it?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed by changing the usb cable which was connected to PC and device.
Before that restarting dev machine, eclipse, even the device dint help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help for sure, but I had a similar problem and I solved it by changing my workspace to a different folder where I placed copies of the projects and changed the names of the folders just one caracter so that It would not tell me they are already in use. Then I worked I just had to import the projects again and I refactored their names to match the code (just the project names).

Answer (score 0):

This error is mostly result of incorrect permissions set for "ddms"/ "android" scrips residing in "your sdk location"/tools.

If you are getting only

```
Sending tracking request failed!
```

error then change the permissions assigned to tools/android. 
To do that open the directory "your sdk location"/tools/ using file browser. You should see a file named android, right click-> properties -> permissions tab -> select allow executing and program. [chmod].

If your error is

```
Sending jdwp tracking request failed!
```

then you need to apply same procedure described above for "your sdk location/tools/ddms"