# Debugging simple android project

Tags: android, debugging

I'm new to Java and more than I'm new to Android. After reading and trying some tutorials I was thinking to make an mp3 player application, but I'm stuck already. I assume that my runtime error is in the following method and more specifically the if condition.

```
public void pausePlay(){
    if(player.isPlaying()){
        demoPause();
    } else {
        demoPlay();
    }
}
```

Maybe I'll be able to solve my problem, but my debugger doesn't work. Or I don't know how to use the debugger. The following links are a printscreen of my [debugger](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/821/debugproblem.png/), [DDMS](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/19/ddmsproblem.png/) and [LogCat](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/823/logcatmaximized.png/). Also on [github](https://github.com/alexa07/play-me) I posted my repository.

Comment: Your Git link appears to be broken. Can you post the LogCat output when you receive the exception? I see from your SC it's an IllegalStateException, but the LogCat will help us drill down farther to the root of the problem. Also, have you tried debugging the code step by step to identify what line is actually breaking your app?

Comment: Android's LogCat will help you handling your exceptions. It logs and displays them. You can view the logcat by switching your view in eclipse from Java to "DDMS".

Comment: What's the problem with the debugger?  Seems to be working fine from the screenshot.  I assume that you mean "how do I use the debugger?"

Comment: @bschultz the github works fine now.

Comment: @Copa I've added the DDMS ptrintscreen

Comment: @mikeng Please don't go on a single-word fixing spree. Fixing that one word is fine, but give the whole post a once over and fix all issues. In plenty of your suggested edits, there is more than enough that should still be fixed.

Comment: Ok, @Bart. Point taken. I'll try to look over the whole post in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mikeng. It makes reviewing a lot more pleasurable and we won't have to bump the same post more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse try the following steps to debug your code:

1.Put a break point in your code where you think the problem is(the app will pause in device when it reaches that code later you can continue to look code flow by pressing F6)

2.Click ddms->device-> If the device is attached it will show you the list of processes, select your process and click green debug icon at top of device.

3.Run your app, when the code flow reaches break point app will pause a dialog appears in eclipse click yes to continue. Next you can continue debugging in eclipse.